# Is there a way to use Orange on a remote server or in the cloud?

Tags: python, orange, cloud-computing

My question there is a way to run the Orange, not on a local computer, but on a remote server, even in the cloud? My notebook has only 8GB memory and limited number of CPU core, which is insufficient for real-world data mining task, however I can use much powerful (remote) server machines.